# How can I use markdown files on a (different) GitHub repo as source for a static Next JS site?

Tags: github, next.js

I'm trying to get a small blog up and running using Next JS. I'd like to keep the markdown (and .mdx) files on a different repo from the site itself. With Gatsby this was no issue using gatsby-source-git, is there a similar way of doing things for Next JS?

If someone could point me to the right docs that would be awesome too, my google-fu isn't working. All the official docs for next-mdx-remote just use `const source = 'Some **mdx** text'` and don't go into detail about *how* to get that source into Next JS.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @Austen I abandoned the idea in the end, but had some limited success writing a script that downloaded the files into the local file structure. Fire that script pre-build. As far a s I know there isn't a gatsby like plugin.